# How to get hashed password in /etc/shadow using getpwnam()?

Tags: users, password, authentication

Apparently there is a function ([getpwnam](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getpwnam.3.html)) that given a username, will return the appropriate entry in `/etc/passwd` with the other details for that user (shell, uid, gid, etc.).

However, I have no idea how to get that function working with the shadow password file (`/etc/shadow`). Is this possible? The application will be running as `root`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole point of the shadow password file is that `getpwnam` *doesn't* return passwords from it.  You need to look at [`man 3 shadow`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/shadow) and [`getspnam`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getspnam.3.html) in particular.

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible due to 2 reasons:

- The shadow file is one method of authentication in modern system. Some of them does not involve real password at all - what should return if user is authenticated by fingerprint? Why should it break any application?
- Giving the hashed string for non-root application would enable off-line attacks.

It is system-specific file anyway with no so much complicated structure so if you need it you can write your own parser.